# Blackberry 5.x | Is old blackberry have NowPlayingConnection equivalent

Tags: java, blackberry, media-player, blackberry-10

I have developed a simple audio player app on `c++` for `Blackberry 10` platform and now want to do the same for `Blackberry 5.x` by using `java`.

Blackberry 10 has [`NowPlayingConnection`](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__multimedia__nowplayingconnection.html) to be able show current state of player from anywhere.

[image]

Does old blackberry have such kind of UI dialog (system or custom)?

Comment: But I can extend `Dialog` class and show it when app in background. So theoretically this is possible. Correct?

Comment: Show what?  What your app is currently playing?  Why not?  But that is not what you asked is it?  You asked if there was a way of finding out what any other app was playing.  AFAIK, there is no way of finding the Player Objects in use by other applications.  And if you can't find them then you can't figure out if they are playing anything can you.  And even if you could find them, I don't believe there is an interface to determine what they are playing.  But I presume you have already looked at this?